# Finding total value of a given portfolio: Java

Tags: java

I know we are not allowed to let someone do homework questions. I did mine, I just need someone to check my java work. These are hand-written work, don't have the classes on computer:

these are the APIs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRaiO.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9bs1.jpg

The question asked to "Write a code fragment in JAVA that will determine the total value of the given Portfolio."

```
Money totalValue = new Money();
Portfolio investments = new Portfolio();
totalValue = investments.getCash();
```

Not sure if this is a trick question or not, because its worth a lot of mark. but it seems straight forward. Can someone tell me if my code is right?

If I disobey any rule, dont ban me just delete this :/

Answer (score 2):

The total value of the portfolio is not just the cash, you need to add the value of the stocks as well. You need to first get the stock price and multiple with the quantity of stock owned and add them all to the cash for the total value.